# Can I use the C-preprocssor to convert an integer to a string?

Tags: c

There's got to be a way to do this...

I have a header file, version.h with one line...

```
#define VERSION 9
```

and a few files use the defined value of VERSION as an integer.
That's fine.

Without changing the way VERSION is defined, I need to build an
initialized "what" string that contains that value,
so I need something like this...

```
char *whatversion = "@(#)VERSION: " VERSION;
```

obviously this doesn't compile, so somehow I need to get a 
string of the preprocessed value of VERSION essentially giving this...

```
char *whatversion = "@(#)VERSION: " "9";
```

Any ideas?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a macro, you can use the "stringify" operator (`#`) which will do exactly what you want:

```
#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR2(x)
#define STRING_VERSION STR(VERSION)

#define VERSION 9

#include <stdio>
int main() {
  printf("VERSION = %02d\n", VERSION);
  printf("%s", "@(#)VERSION: " STRING_VERSION "\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Yes, you do need the double indirection in the macro call. Without it, you'd get `"VERSION"` instead of `"9"`.

You can read more about this in the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) (although it is fully standard C/C++).

Answer (score 5):

It is not a datatype, it is a token.  A blob of text.

`K & R` talk about concatenating values:

```
 The preprocessor operator ## provides a way to concatenate actual arguments
 during macro expansion. If a parameter in the replacement text is adjacent
 to a ##, the parameter is replaced by the actual argument, the ## and
 surrounding white space are removed, and the result is re-scanned. For example,
 the macro paste concatenates its two arguments:

    #define paste(front, back) front ## back

    so paste(name, 1) creates the token name1.
```

-- try that.  #define the string before you get to `char *version=`

Comment: You can only paste tokens together, which is pretty limiting. You cannot easily generate a string, for example, and `#(@)VERSION` is *not* a token, so it cannot be concatenated with anything. (`"#(@)VERSION"` is a token, but you cannot concatenate a string token to another token, unless that token is a length indicator. Fortunately, you don't need to concatenate string tokens.)